# How to query Firebase Database in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question concerning Android Studio Firebase Database. I am currently trying to put a condition on a query in order to send a notification for a selected Query, in this case `send notification if MenuId=01` selected in my Firebase database, hope you can help, thank you.

```
    if (request.getFoods().isEmpty()) {
         Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "Your cart is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else{

         final DatabaseReference MyMenuId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("foods");
         final Query data = MyMenuId.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo("01"); // get all node with menuID=01
```

Trying to figure out how to put a condition on this `MenuId=01` to only send a notification when this MenuId is selected:

```
    data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String order_number = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                requests.child(order_number).setValue(request);

                // Delete Cart
                new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You have ordered from menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                sendNotificationOrder(order_number);
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You did not order from menuId 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }**
```

Comment: share your firebase database..

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to put condition just use
>   addListenerForSingleValueEvent, It will execute only once the
>   target value is found.. You were using addValueListener which is listening to all the values in the node and you want to find a single value, better to use single value listener.

```
DatabaseReference MyMenuId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("foods").child("MenuId").orderByChild("city").equalTo(
 final Query data = MyMenuId.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo("01"); // get all node with menuID=01

          data.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { 
        @Override 
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String order_number = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                requests.child(order_number).setValue(request);

                // Delete Cart 
                new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You have ordered from menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                sendNotificationOrder(order_number);
                Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You did not order from menuId 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onDataChange` gets called, no matter whether there is a result or not. To check whether there is an actual result, use `dataSnapshot.exists()`:

```
data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            String order_number = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            requests.child(order_number).setValue(request);

            // Delete Cart
            new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You have ordered from menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            sendNotificationOrder(order_number);
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You did not order from menuId 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
```

---

If you need to actually process the result, keep the following in mind.

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So your code needs to handle the list of results by iterating over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
data.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String order_number = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            requests.child(order_number).setValue(request);

            // Delete Cart
            new Database(getBaseContext()).cleanCart();
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You have ordered from menu 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            sendNotificationOrder(order_number);
            Toast.makeText(Cart.this, "You did not order from menuId 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        }
```